# Why is my word generator not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a random word generator (mostly nonsensical words).

The point is for it to:

- Generate a certain number of strings of certain lengths
- They must contain a vowel, and if there is no vowel, it iterates again.

But for whatever reason after I enter both `x` and `y` the program does nothing.

I tried adding `print(attempt)` after `attempt = random.choice(sUpper)`, and it just generated:

```
H
G
E
```

etc.

Here is the program in question:

```
import random
sUpper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
sLower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
class Word:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
    def build(self):
            while 1:
                attempt = random.choice(sUpper)
                a = 0
                while a <= (self.length-1):
                    attempt += random.choice(sLower)
                    a += 1
                for i in vowels:
                    if i in attempt:
                        word = attempt
                        break
            return word
while 1:
    x = int(input('Length: '))
    y = int(input('Number: '))
    z = Word(x)
    w = 1
    while w <= y:
        print(z.build())
        w += 1
```

Comment: There's nothing to terminate the `while 1` in `build`.

Comment: What about the break?

Comment: Yes, your `break` is only going to jump out of the for loop.

Comment: Oh. How should I go about correcting it?

Comment: Somehow `a <= self.length - 1` looks really weird ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your build function to this:

```
def build(self):
    running = True
    while running:
        attempt = random.choice(sUpper)
        a = 0
        while a <= (self.length-1):
            attempt += random.choice(sLower)
            a += 1
        for i in vowels:
            if i in attempt:
                word = attempt
                running = False
                break
    return word
```

Comment: It ran without a problem for me. Is it not giving you any output at all?

Comment: Oh wait, your for loop is outside your while loop. I changed the indentation and it worked. Thanks!